# TypeError: User.serializeUser is not a function

Tags: javascript, passport.js

I am trying to add authentication in my app with `passport.js` and `passport-local-mongoose` and getting the err i tried to solve it with different approach say by using `serialze` and `deserialize` function from `passport.js` then it actually work. What i am doing wrong here  pls help

i also tried different solution given on this plate-form with regards to this question

```
**TypeError: User.serializeUser is not a function**
```

user.js file in models directory

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');

const User = new Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String
});

User.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

const User =  mongoose.model('User', User);
exports.User = User
```

app.js file looks like

```
const   express = require('express'),
        mongoose = require('mongoose'),
        passport = require('passport'),
        bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
        User = ('./models/user'),
        LocalStrategy = require('passport-local'),
        passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');


mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/authdemoapp', {
    useUnifiedTopology:true,
    useNewUrlParser:true
});

const app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}))
// passport and sessions setup
app.use(require('express-session')({
    secret: 'My Name Is IzharUlhaque',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
})); 

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());


passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());
```